# OCMock stub method with two block completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm trying to mock a class (`AFHTTPSessionManager`) that has a method with 2 blocks, how can I trigger them manually, like, making two test that one will use the first block implementation and the other test will use the second block implementation.

```
[manager GET:path parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    //First block to trigger.
    //logic code here
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    //Second block to trigger.
    //logic code here
}];
```

Currently, it will always trigger the second block.

I've mocked the class like this:

```
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey code:-1009 userInfo:nil];
NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object", @"key", nil];

id mockAFHTTPSessionManager = OCMClassMock([AFHTTPSessionManager class]);

OCMStub([mockAFHTTPSessionManager alloc]).andReturn(mockAFHTTPSessionManager);
OCMStub([mockAFHTTPSessionManager initWithBaseURL:OCMOCK_ANY]).andReturn(mockAFHTTPSessionManager);
OCMStub([mockAFHTTPSessionManager GET:OCMOCK_ANY parameters:OCMOCK_ANY success:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:OCMOCK_ANY, responseObject, nil]) failure:([OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:OCMOCK_ANY, error, nil])]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a specific reason you're stubbing alloc / initWithBaseURL, but here's how *I* mock AFHTTPSessionManager:

```
id mockSessionManager = OCMClassMock([AFHTTPSessionManager class]);
OCMStub([mockSessionManager manager]).andReturn(mockSessionManager);
```

Now, for testing the success / failure block invocations, I'm going to make a suggestion that saved me a bunch of headaches: don't inline your blocks. Instead, return the blocks from a separate method and test those methods individually. Then, in the test that is testing the actual `GET:parameters:success:failure` call, you just need to expect that the methods that return your completion blocks are called.

Here's an example:

**MyClass.m**

```
- (void)doGetRequest
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://something.whatever.com"
             parameters:nil 
                success:[self getSuccessBlock] 
                failure:[self getFailureBlock]];
}

- (void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask*, id))getSuccessBlock
{
    return ^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, id responseObject)
        {
            // handle success
        };
}

- (void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask*, NSError*))getFailure
{
    return ^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, NSError* error)
        {
            // handle failure
        }
}
```

**MyClassTests.m**

```
- (void)testDoGetRequest
{
    MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    id mockMyClass = OCMPartialMock(myClass);
    id mockSessionManager = OCMClassMock([AFHTTPSessionManager class]);
    OCMStub([mockSessionManager manager]).andReturn(mockSessionManager);

    id successBlock = ^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, id o){};
    id failureBlock = ^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, NSError* error){};
    OCMExpect([mockMyClass getSuccess]).andReturn(successBlock);
    OCMExpect([mockMyClass getFailure]).andReturn(failureBlock);

    OCMExpect([mockSessionManager GET:OCMOCK_ANY
                           parameters:OCMOCK_ANY 
                              success:successBlock
                              failure:failureBlock]);

    [myClass doGetRequest];

    OCMVerifyAll(mockMyClass);
    OCMVerifyAll(mockSessionManager);
}

- (void)testGetSuccessBlock
{
    MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    // setup expectations
    NSURLSessionDataTaks* fakeTask = // whatever you need here
    id fakeResponseObject = // whatever you need here
    [myClass getSuccessBlock](fakeTask, fakeResponseObject);
    // evaluate expectations
}

- (void)testGetFailureBlock
{
    MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    // setup expectations
    NSURLSessionDataTaks* fakeTask = // whatever you need here
    NSError* fakeError = // whatever you need here
    [myClass getFailureBlock](fakeTask, fakeError);
    // evaluate expectations
}
```

(I wrote this basically off the top of my head, so some of the syntax might not be 100%, but you should get the idea)